# how can change my index directory without 403 error in another subdomains?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have 2 subdomains a.example.com and b.example.com

I need to change my index directory from example.com to example.com/home/index.php without /home/ in addressbar, in otherword if user visit example.com/home/ or example.com/home/index.php redirect to **example.com** but show example.com/home/ content.

I set DirectoryIndex /home/index.php in example.com htaccess file but a.example.com and b.example.com give error.

Answer (score 0):

Set Directory option in Apache configuration or any server configuration file to example.com/home

Answer (score 0):

in otherword, i need to exclude my /home/ directory from address.
this my htaccess code:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1 [NC]`

with above code example.com show example.com/home/ content. but example.com/home/ is still.
now i need if user visit example.com/home/ redirect to example.com. or if user visit example.com/home/another-page redirect to example.com/another-page

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

The R flag creates a redirection from memory.